# Calculating percentages with COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns `owneridname`, `createdon`,`svb_contactname` in a table called **incident**. I am trying to calculate the percentage of NULL and non-NULL values for each person using the svb_contactname column (the `PercYes` and `PercNo` column) but I am having trouble getting the percentages to work.

Sample (example) data table:

| owneridname | createdon | svb_contactname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brittany Miller | 7/3/2023 | NULL |
| Christine Hak | 7/3/2023 | Jeremiah Smith |
| Dawn Cembellin | 7/3/2023 | Robert Drago |
| Dominic Sanchez | 7/3/2023 | Frank Kirby |
| Dylinn Guiles | 7/3/2023 | NULL |

When I attempt to use `COUNT(svb_contactname)/COUNT(*) [PercYes]` it only seems to return a **1** or a **0** (as you can see in the results table below) when I am looking for a decimal number to be returned as the result. Same is for the `PercNo` column.

```
SELECT
  owneridname,
  CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date) [Week],
  FORMAT(createdon, 'MMMM', 'en-US') [Month],
  COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [Yes], /*Counts non-NULL values*/
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [No], /*Counts only NULL values in the column*/
  COUNT(svb_contactname)/COUNT(*) [PercYes],
  (COUNT(*)-COUNT(svb_contactname))/COUNT(*) [PercNo]
FROM incident
WHERE createdon >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1)
GROUP BY
  owneridname,
  CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date),
  FORMAT(createdon, 'MMMM', 'en-US')
ORDER BY
  Week DESC;
```

Initial results:

| owneridname | Week Date | Month | Yes | No | PercYes | PercNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 7/3/2023 | July | 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Margo Johnson | 7/3/2023 | July | 18 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| Caitlin Dakota | 7/3/2023 | July | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| Matthew Drake | 7/3/2023 | July | 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| Dan Bingo | 7/3/2023 | July | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I am looking to produce these results:

| owneridname | Week Date | Month | Yes | No | PercYes | PercNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 7/3/2023 | July | 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Margo Johnson | 7/3/2023 | July | 18 | 7 | .72 | .28 |
| Caitlin Dakota | 7/3/2023 | July | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| Matthew Drake | 7/3/2023 | July | 5 | 2 | .71 | .29 |
| Dan Bingo | 7/3/2023 | July | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: You are doing integer division, add a decimal expression to resolve eg `COUNT(svb_contactname) * 1.0`

Comment: Considering you want an average, perhaps using `AVG` would be better: `AVG(CASE WHEN svb_contactname IS NULL THEN 0. ELSE 1. END)`

Comment: @Stu This worked! However how can I reduce the decimal places? I attempted wrapping the functions with ROUND but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: `CAST`/`CONVERT` it, @hobosapien . `ROUND`img doesn't change the data type or the precision/scale of a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you divide integers, the result is integer. Just by making one of them float, you will get decimal as result:

```
  SELECT
      owneridname,
      CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date) [Week],
      FORMAT(createdon, 'MMMM', 'en-US') [Month],
      COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [Yes], /*Counts non-NULL values*/
      COUNT(*) - COUNT(svb_contactname) AS [No], /*Counts only NULL values in the column*/
      CAST(COUNT(svb_contactname) AS FLOAT)/COUNT(*) [PercYes],
      CAST((COUNT(*)-COUNT(svb_contactname)) AS FLOAT)/COUNT(*) [PercNo]
    FROM incident
    WHERE createdon >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1)
    GROUP BY
      owneridname,
      CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, createdon), 0) as date),
      FORMAT(createdon, 'MMMM', 'en-US')
    ORDER BY
      Week DESC;
```

Change this for decimals:

```
ROUND(CAST(COUNT(svb_contactname) AS FLOAT)/COUNT(*) * 100, 2) [PercYes],
ROUND(CAST((COUNT(*)-COUNT(svb_contactname)) AS FLOAT)/COUNT(*) * 100, 2) [PercNo]
```

Comment: That worked, however how I would keep it to two decimal places? Some of the results are giving 10+ decimals

Comment: See my edit for decimal